# MiXiM building no such file or directory error

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, omnet++, mixim, 802.11p

I failed to build the MiXiM on Ubuntu 14.04.3 and OMNet 4.6, the error message is: ”fatal error: Mac80211Pkt_m.h: No such file or directory”. From the manual of OMNet it can be found that the file Mac80211Pkt_m.h should be generated automatically by the compiler during the building process, but it was shown by the error message that the file was not generated automatically. I am confused about the problem, how can I solve this? Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error message. Here is how I bypassed the problem:

1. Extract "mixim-2.3.tar.gz" (tar xvzf mixim-2.3.tar.gz)
2. Change into the directory just extracted (cd mixim-2.3)
3. Execute "make makefiles"
4. Start the build by "make"
5. Import the just built project using the omnet++ IDE

Comment: If you choose this approach, make sure that you always compile from command line! Otherwise, the generated code may be out of date.